# Eclipse backups

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I accidentally deleted a folder with the project. Restore failed using Recuva (which is strange, I specifically did not touch the folder after deleting to avoid accidentally prezapisat sector). It can store backups Eclipse projects? Can I still recover your project?

Comment: It may be stupid proposal, but you can use source code control systems like git and makes commits / push them into remote repositories. :) why not?

Comment: Michael, project in very base state. Only one header in 200 lines and one c source :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted a folder within the project, you may be able to use [Eclipse Local History](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm?cp=0_1_0_17) to recover it.

1. Right-click on the folder or project containing the files/folders you want to recover
2. Select *Restore from Local History...*
3. Select the files you want to recover, and possibly the edition (save revision)
4. Press *Restore*

[image]

Comment: Sadly, the Eclipse Local History is stored in the .metadata.